# Is it possible to dynamically create array of functions for async.series

Tags: javascript, async.js

I want to call the same async function but with different parameters each time using async.series. I am trying to do it by dynamically generating the functions as shown below

```
function makeNotifications(notify,callback){
var functionContainer = [];
 function handler(arg){
    return function() { 
     //   log.debug("Notified ",arg); 
          sendmail(arg,function(maildata) {
        callback(null,arg);
            });
   }

}
for (var i = 0; i < notify.length; i++) {
    var currentArg = notify[i]; 
    log.debug("Notify ", currentArg);
       functionContainer.push(handler(currentArg));
  }
    //use async.series - 
        async.series( functionContainer, function(err,results){
           log.debug(results); 
       });
           callback(null,notify);
    }
```

This does not appear to work though. The function is not executed when the series is run. functionContainer appears to contain NULL. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Pass callback to the [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) function inside the handler. As [async.js](http://caolan.github.io/async/) requires a collection of [async functions](https://caolan.github.io/async/global.html) to execute.

```
function makeNotifications(notify,parent_callback) {
let func_arr = [];
function handler(args) {
    return function(callback) {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            return callback(null,args);
        },2000);
    }
}
_.times(5,(item)=>{
    func_arr.push(handler(item));
});
console.log("function array : ",func_arr);
return async.series(func_arr,(err,data)=>{
    console.log("Final result : ",err?err:data);
    return parent_callback(null,notify);
});
}

makeNotifications([1,2,3],(err,data)=>{});
```

Output :

> function array :  [ [Function], [Function], [Function], [Function], [Function] ]
>
> Final result :  [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]